# Filling in empty dates for df with multiple entries per date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
      date          color     quantity
0     2022-07-01    blue      2
1     2022-07-01    red       1
2     2022-07-01    yellow    0
3     2022-07-03    blue      0
4     2022-07-03    red       3
5     2022-07-03    yellow    1
6     2022-07-04    blue      1
7     2022-07-04    red       0
8     2022-07-04    yellow    2
9     2022-07-07    blue      2
10    2022-07-07    red       1
11    2022-07-07    yellow    0
```

How would I go about getting this to fill in the empty dates, with each color having a quantity of 0 on those dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
date = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='D')

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([date, df['color'].unique()])
out = (df.set_index(['date', 'color'])
       .reindex(index, fill_value=0)
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

      level_0 level_1  quantity
0  2022-07-01    blue         2
1  2022-07-01     red         1
2  2022-07-01  yellow         0
3  2022-07-02    blue         0
4  2022-07-02     red         0
5  2022-07-02  yellow         0
6  2022-07-03    blue         0
7  2022-07-03     red         3
8  2022-07-03  yellow         1
9  2022-07-04    blue         1
10 2022-07-04     red         0
11 2022-07-04  yellow         2
12 2022-07-05    blue         0
13 2022-07-05     red         0
14 2022-07-05  yellow         0
15 2022-07-06    blue         0
16 2022-07-06     red         0
17 2022-07-06  yellow         0
18 2022-07-07    blue         2
19 2022-07-07     red         1
20 2022-07-07  yellow         0
```